# Reset an html element after error with VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping, classname

On a scraper macro I am trying to move over an error and return "input error" when there is no data to crawl.

For now I am using this:

```
Public Function translate()

    Set thisWbs = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    link = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en"
    i = 2

    ie.Visible = True

    LastRow = thisWbs.Range("B" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = thisWbs.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)

    For Each cell In Rng

        my_url = link
        ie.navigate my_url
        
        Wait 2
    
        While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
        
        ie.document.getElementById("source").innerText = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i)
        
        Wait 2

        If ie.document.getElementsByClassName("empty-placeholder placeholder")(0).innerText = "Translation" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = "input error"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("tlid-translation translation")(0).innerText
        End If

        Wait 1
        
        ie.document.getElementsByClassName("empty-placeholder placeholder")(0).innerText = " "
        
        i = i + 1

    Next cell

    ie.Quit

    MsgBox "Done"
    
End Function
```

It work and It returns "input error" for the first error found, but when it finds another error the class remains " " as was set before, so It couldn't found The "Translate" again and stops working. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you do not use the line `ie.document.getElementsByClassName("empty-placeholder placeholder")(0).innerText = " "`?

Comment: If I delete that line, after returning "input error" once, it will return "input error" for all the remaining searches

Comment: I can see only a slice of your code. I suppose that your code navigates to another URL. Isn't this assumption true? If yes, your code should read the new class name `innerText`. Returning "Translation" is not an error which must be cleared. Are you sure that another URL is analyzed by your code?  Where, in your code, `my_url` is changed? If not, it will be the same until the code exists the loop.

Comment: I have edited and added all the code

Comment: Your code navigates from a lot of times to the same URL. It is normal to behave like it does. What do you want/need, in fact? The same class of the same URL will always return the same `innerText`.

Comment: I just want to translate the cells from column B using google translate and return the translated values in column C

Comment: Then, you don't... You must adapt the original link with the word to be checked. you should do something like: `my_URL = link & "&text=" & yourSearchWord.` Where  "your search word" should be taken from your file and processed to replace spaces with `%20`. Something like: `yourSearchWord = Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).value, " ", "%20")`.

Comment: Use _option explicit_ the top of your module and declare all your variables. Also, indenting and spacing, such as per the edit, makes the code flow easier to follow.

Comment: You are better off having the _While ie.readyState <> 4 Or ie.Busy: DoEvents: Wend_ before the _Wait 2_ if you truly intend to add that wait time after page load.

Comment: I don't know why you are including this line _ie.document.getElementsByClassName("empty-placeholder placeholder")(0).innerText = " "_ ? Is the process not go to the page and enter text from sheet and then check a specific element's innerText to see if there is a "Translation" or not?  Doubt you need those additional _Wait_ calls.  And please use explicit sheet references rather than Activesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Private Sub translate()
  Dim thisWbs As Worksheet, IE As Object, link As String
  Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, my_url As String
  
    Set thisWbs = ActiveSheet
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    link = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en"
    
    'IE.Visible = True
    lastRow = thisWbs.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    thisWbs.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Clear
    
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        my_url = link & "&text=" & Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, " ", "%20")
        IE.navigate my_url

        While IE.readyState <> 4 Or IE.Busy: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))

        If IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("empty-placeholder placeholder")(0).innerText = "Translation" Then
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = "input error"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range("C" & i) = IE.Document.getElementsByClassName("tlid-translation translation")(0).innerText
        End If
    Next i

    IE.Quit
    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

I tested it. I adapted yours in order to make it working.

Now, try the next function (much faster and reliable, not needing Internet Explorer), please:

```
Private Function GTranslate(strInput As String, strFromLang As String, strToLang As String) As String
    Dim strURL As String, objHTTP As Object, objHTML As Object, objDivs As Object, objDiv As Variant
    
    strURL = "https://translate.google.com/m?hl=" & strFromLang & _
        "&sl=" & strFromLang & _
        "&tl=" & strToLang & _
        "&ie=UTF-8&prev=_m&q=" & strInput
        
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    objHTTP.Open "GET", strURL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ""
    
    Set objHTML = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    With objHTML
        .Open
        .Write objHTTP.responseText
        .Close
    End With
    
    Set objDivs = objHTML.getElementsByTagName("div")
    For Each objDiv In objDivs
        If objDiv.className = "t0" Then
            GTranslate = objDiv.innerText: Exit For
        End If
    Next objDiv
    
    Set objHTML = Nothing: Set objHTTP = Nothing
End Function
```

I found it on the internet (some years before), adapted it for my need and now for yours...

Your code, using the above function, will become:

```
Private Sub Google_translate()
  Dim thisWbs As Worksheet
  Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long
  
  Set thisWbs = ActiveSheet
  lastRow = thisWbs.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
  thisWbs.Range("C2:C" & lastRow).Clear
  
  For i = 2 To lastRow
    thisWbs.Range("C" & i).Value = GTranslate(thisWbs.Range("B" & i).Value, "auto", "en")
  Next i
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

Comment: link = "https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=en&text="
and
    my_url = link & Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, " ", "%20")
or
    my_url = link & cell & Replace(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & i).Value, " ", "%20")
both versions gives error on ie.navigate my_url

Comment: Just copy my answer code line. You missed  "&text="...

Comment: I didn't missed it, I have included it into the main link

Comment: @Psko: Please, copy the exact code line, as you have it.

Comment: Nice idea though I would go with EncodeURL  function call, in the first instance, rather than using Replace.

Comment: @Psko: I adapted your code in a way to make it working. Merge acum?

Comment: @Psko: Still alive? Did you find time to test the above codes?

Comment: Didn't test it, I have found another way, I will share it tomorrow

Comment: @Psko: If you did not test anything, no need to share anything. I know how to do such a thing... I thought I was helping you, but it looks I was wrong.